# When you open the windows in the house in order for fresh air to come in?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I just cannot find this in any dictionary.

How is it called in English when someone opens the windows (and/or the door) of a house in order to let the fresh air come in? Please note that I'm interested in the phenomenon that occours *naturally* (and *not* through artificial ventillation).

Also, what is the name of when in this situation the air starts to flow and there is a wind-like movement of air in the house? Capable of slamming the door.

In Hungarian, letting the wind in is called *szellőztetés* and the wind itself is called called *huzat* (although the latter has multiple meanings).

(In my language, the same word is also used when you open a car window when it moves and you can feel the air on your head, some people dont like it. On the other hand, in the house it's usually a good experience.)

Comment: A word for the current of air itself might be *draft* (American spelling) or *draught* (British spelling).

Comment: @KaiserOctavius thanks! I think I confused that one with the 'unfinished' draft! Then it may be, 'let the draught in'?

Comment: You've done a good job asking this question. I believe it might have been an even better fit for [ell.SE]

Comment: @naxa, Yes, you can say that.

Comment: @J.R. you may be right, I didn't know about ELL! Thanks!

Comment: The English would sooner take their carpets up than air the house. No wonder there isn't a word for it! Just kidding...

Comment: @naxa I would say: A **gust** of wind explains why a door suddenly slams shut.

Comment: @DominicCronin actually used the verb that is the answer - "Air" - one "airs" a room or house (or indeed bed) by opening the windows & doors (or removing sheets).

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I thought of was the phrasal verb [***air out***](http://www.onelook.com/?w=air+out&ls=a).

You can also drop the word *out* and retain the same meaning. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/air_28#air_32) explains it as follows:

> **air** or **air out** (*v.*)
>    [intransitive/transitive] if you *air* a place or it *airs*, you open the doors and windows to let fresh air in

As for what slams the door, that could be the *air current,* or, more informally, the *[breeze](http://books.google.com/books?id=AyFAAAAAIAAJ&q=%22the%20breeze%20slammed%20the%20door%22&dq=%22the%20breeze%20slammed%20the%20door%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ED3LUfzZMKHc4AP57IGIAw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA)*.

Comment: Formally or otherwise, I'd always say the *wind*.

Comment: The single-word verb is used far more commonly than its two-word synonym in the UK, I believe, J.R.

Comment: @Tim: For the record, I wasn't meaning to provide an exhaustive list. What closes the door could be called _the wind_, or it might be called a _rush of wind_, a _gust of wind_, a _blowing breeze_, a _flow of air_, a _waft of air_, and probably a few other things as well. There's no single name for it.

Comment: @Edwin: I believe you're correct. In fact, the [British edition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/air_28#air_32) of that same dictionary doesn't even mention _air out_. But _air out_ is not uncommon at all in the US.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say "airing" or "aeration", actually.

> air·ing
>   /ˈe(ə)riNG/
>   Noun
>   An exposure to warm or fresh air, for the purpose of ventilating.
>
> aeration
>   the process of exposing to air (so as to purify); "the aeration of the soil".

Answer (score 2):

Now, "airing" works, but "ventilate" also works.  Check Wikipedia on this one, because ventilate can either be "active" or "forced", or it can also be "natural".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventilate

> Ventilation includes both the exchange of air to the outside as well
>   as circulation of air within the building. It is one of the most
>   important factors for maintaining acceptable indoor air quality in
>   buildings. Methods for ventilating a building may be divided into
>   mechanical/forced and natural types.

As a plus, "ventilate" has within itself the word "vent", which implies an opening, whereas "airing" has no such implication.

Comment: As for your very last point, I'd say that _air_ **does** have the implication of fresh air. After all, the word is **air**.

Comment: An "airing" could refer to trotting out an idea for public comment.  Air need not be fresh.  But I wouldn't disagree with you -- it is just that "vent" occurs inside "*vent*illation".

Comment: _Vent_ can also mean vent _emotionally_, or it can be part of a medical treatment – so the same can be said for both words. (By the way, I'm not bashing _ventilate_; you're right, it's a candidate worthy of consideration.)